# Linking Visual Studio Multi-device Hybrid App support with BB10 WebWorks

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Since Cordova supports building applications for BlackBerry10. I thought I would combine the BB10 WebWorks SDK with Visual Studio cordova support to gain an additional platform when writing hybrid applications.

So far I have managed to coerce Visual Studio into building a BlackBerry 10 application target (a fair amount of fiddling with VS javascript files) but don't know how to get it to install/launch on the device or for that matter inside an emulator.

Looking for information as to how Cordova and the device hooks are managed or is this part of the framework managed within Visual Studio as VS plugin...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from Visual Studio and will have to drop down to the command line and use the BlackBerry tools to send the app to the device. I just asked a Visual Studio developer at the Microsoft Ignite conference for you.